# Create new object from string

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a new object from string. Here is my code:

```
if (gettype($value) === 'object') {
                    $className = explode('\\',get_class($value))[2];
                    $className.='DatabaseNode';
                    //First check 
                    $newObject = new $className($value);
                    //Second check 
                    $newObject = new LocationDatabaseNode($value);

                }
```

The first one returns

> Class 'LocationDatabaseNode' not found in...

and the second one works fine.
Do I use it correctly?

Problem solved. I added the all path to the class and now it works :)

Comment: Have you included a file with the class in it?

Comment: yep, You are using it correctly. May something is wrong with any other part of you code. Check `First` and ``Second` separately.

Comment: Not sure why you apparently expect the `$classname` definition to result in the string "Location". Did you really make sure `$className` does indeed contain "LocationDatabaseNode"? How?

Comment: Problem solved. i added the all path to the class and now its work :)

Comment: please answer your question as answer and consider keeping only question in the question section